# "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" and "org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)"

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3

So I wanted to use chromedriver on my raspberry pi 3b and I got this error.

I already installed the linux32 bit version of the chromedriver and it also finds the driver. But during initializing the driver it says:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver: ELF�4���4: not found
/home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver: 2: /home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

After that I get a timeout and this error:

```
Sep 06, 2018 4:47:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'raspberrypi', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '4.14.34-v7+', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at xxxxxxxx.initialize(xxxxxxxx.java:39)
at xxxxxxxx.main(xxxxxxxx.java:24)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out 
waiting for [http://localhost:18689/status] to be available after 20014 ms
at 
org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverServic 
e.java:187)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:148)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)`
```

My code:

```
System.out.println("Starting Bot..");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/pi/Desktop/chromedriver");
    System.out.println("yes");

    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Nexus 5");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    System.out.println("yes2");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: @JeffC that's correct format for Linux. Gareth, does it work with the basic configuration (i.e. no mobile emulation, no ChromeOptions at all, just driver instantiation)?

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
```

...implies that the underlying OS was unable to start the **chromedriver** process.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.12.0**.
- But your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_65** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u65* and *Selenium Client v3.12.0*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: And if this happens periodically?

Comment: @sevnight I will update the answer in a short while and let you know